# set(filter) repetition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I maintain a set that needs to be progressively shrunk, according to various conditions.

For example:

```
acceptable = read_input()
acceptable.rank_by_x()
acceptable = set(filter(is_rank_x_top_100, acceptable))
acceptable.rank_by_y()
acceptable = set(filter(is_rank_y_top_10, acceptable))
```

It works, but the `set(filter())` construct looks ugly. Is there a better way to do that? Or is it better to just subclass set to add a method that does the same?

Comment: Do you know about list comprehensions? Filter is a special case of a list comprehension. [x for x in xs if x == y] results in a list of all xs that are ys.

Comment: @Wes: that would make it just uglier.. `set([x for x in acceptable if is_hot(x)])`

Comment: @KennyTM `#...` make various calculation, which depend on the current state of `acceptable`, and the results of which affect the functions called in the future. My example doesn't make it clear, so I am rewriting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may collapse this to:

```
acceptable = set()
#...
acceptable = set(filter(is_rank_y_top_10,
                        filter(is_rank_x_top_100, acceptable)))
```

Or use comprehensions:

```
acceptable = set()
#...
acceptable = set(i for i in acceptable
                 if is_rank_x_top_100(i) and is_rank_y_top_10(i))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Python 3 or Python 2.7, you can use set comprehensions:

```
acceptable = {i for i in acceptable if is_rank_x_top_100(i)}
```